# Regex: Exclude matches containing specific strings

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm not really versatile in regex, especially multi-line so i hope someone can help me out here.

Based on the following example, I'm trying to find all the field definitions of type Code that don't have the "TableRelation"-property set.

so in this example, this would be the field "Holding Name"

```
table 123 "MyTable"
{
    fields
    {
        field(1000; "Created on"; Date)
        {
            Caption = 'Created on';
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
            Editable = false;
        }
        field(2000; "Created by"; Code[50])
        {
            Caption = 'Created by';
            TableRelation = User."User Name";
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
            Editable = false;
        }
        field(3000; Resigned; Boolean)
        {
            Caption = 'Resigned';
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
        }
        field(4000; "Holding No."; Code[20])
        {
            Caption = 'Holding No.';
            TableRelation = Contact."No." where(Type = const(Company));
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;

            trigger OnValidate()
            var
               [...]
            begin
               [...]
            end;

        }
        field(4010; "Holding Name"; Code[100])
        {
            Caption = 'Holding Name';
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
        }
        field(5000; "Geocoding Entry No."; Integer)
        {
            Caption = 'Geocoding Entry No.';
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
        }
    }
    keys
    {
        key(AppliesToContact; "Holding No.", "Holding Name", "Company Level") { }
    }
}
```

I Managed to match the fields of type "Code" properly... `field\(\d+;.+; ?(?:C|c)ode\[\d+\]\)\n?\s*\{(?:\n|.)*?\}`

But i don't know how to correctly exclude matches containing "TableRelation" at least this doesn't work the way I hoped. - I get one HUGE match with it :-(

`field\(\d+;.+; ?(?:C|c)ode\[\d+\]\)\n?\s*\{((?!(T|t)able(R|r)elation)\n*.*)*?\}`

p.s. if you're wondering: The sample I'm parsing is written in AL-Language, a proprietary language for MS Business central.

Comment: Please add the tag language (or tool) with which you are trying to write a regex pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match `field(` and the digits between the square brackets before the closing parenthesis using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) starting with `[^`

The same negated character class approach can also be taken for asserting not `TableRelation` between curly braces.

Not that you can write `(?:C|c)` as `[Cc]` using a character class instead of using an alternation `|`

Assuming the curly brace after field has a single non nested closing curly:

```
field\([^()]+; ?[Cc]ode\[\d+\]\)\s*{(?![^{}]*[Tt]able[Rr]elation)[^{}]*}
```

The pattern matches:

- `field\([^()]+` Match `field(` and 1+ chars other than `(` `)` (which can also match a newline)
- `; ?[Cc]ode` Match `;` optional space and Code/code
- `\[\d+\]\)` Match `[` 1+ digits `])`
- `\s*{` Match optional whitespace chars (which can also match a newline) and `{`
- `(?![^{}]*[Tt]able[Rr]elation)` Negative lookahead, assert not `TableRelation` after the openin curly
- `[^{}]*` Match optional repetitions of any character except `{` `}`
- `}` Match closing  `}`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BFScFJ/1).

Comment: Thank you for your input! apparently VSCode uses a different Engine than the regex demo-website you showed me, but i managed to adapt. Here is my final result:

Comment: `field\(\d+; .*;?[Cc]ode\[\d+\]\)\s*\{(?!(?:\n|.)*[^/]\s?[Tt]able[Rr]elation)[^}]*?\}` - i had to return to my regex to find the field-Line because the Field names can also contain braces. - The `[^\}] inside the negative lookahead somehow didn't work but the following one did. - I also had to escape some of the curly braces because VSC though they where quantifyer brackets. - But i used your example to solve the problem, so have the points

Comment: p.s. i also added `[^/]\s` in front of the TableRelation-property to keep showing Fields with disabled table relation... for some reason the negated characters worked there :-/

Comment: @StefanLippeck If that pattern worked for you, then you can write it as `field\(\d+; .*;?[Cc]ode\[\d+\]\)\s*\{(?![\s\S\r]*?[^/]\s?[Tt]able[Rr]elation)[^}]*?\}` because using `(?:\n|.)*` is very inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

With a caseless research and with a regex engine that allows atomic groups and possessive quantifiers, you can write:

`\bfield\((?>[^);]*;\s*)*code\b[^)]*\)\s*{(?>[^\w}]*+(?!tablerelation\s*=)\w+)*[^\w}]*}`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/7rvYoB/1)

This pattern is based on negative character classes to stop the greedy quantifiers as in The four birds answer.
Atomic groups `(?>...)` and possessive quantifiers `*+` are used to reduce the backtracking. In particular, the presence of `tablerelation` is only tested after a range of non-word characters with a negative lookahead.
Note that the `code` part can be everywhere between the parenthesis after `field`.

Comment: I think it is most certainly a nice solution with the atomic groups ++

Answer (score 1):

The following regex can capture the `Code[...]` value of areas not having 'TableRelation'.

```
/field\([^)]+; Code\[(\d+)\]\)\n\s+{((?!TableRelation).)+?}\n/gs
```

It uses `g`(global) and `s`(dotall) flags.

A notable part of this regexp is the `((?!TableRelation).)+?` expression.

- `(?!TableRelation)` : negative lookahead(should not appear)
- `((?!TableRelation).)+?` : not having 'TableRelation', match as few as possible

I created a simple JS snippet. The code uses two steps to extract.

```js
const regexp = /field\([^)]+; Code\[(\d+)\]\)\n\s+{((?!TableRelation).)+?}\n/gs;

const target = `
table 123 "MyTable"
{
    fields
    {
        field(1000; "Created on"; Date)
        {
            Caption = 'Created on';
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
            Editable = false;
        }
        field(2000; "Created by"; Code[50])
        {
            Caption = 'Created by';
            TableRelation = User."User Name";
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
            Editable = false;
        }
        field(3000; Resigned; Boolean)
        {
            Caption = 'Resigned';
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
        }
        field(4000; "Holding No."; Code[20])
        {
            Caption = 'Holding No.';
            TableRelation = Contact."No." where(Type = const(Company));
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;

            trigger OnValidate()
            var
               [...]
            begin
               [...]
            end;

        }
        field(4010; "Holding Name"; Code[100])
        {
            Caption = 'Holding Name';
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
        }
        field(4050; "Holding Name"; Code[80])
        {
            Caption = 'Holding Name 2';
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
        }
        field(5000; "Geocoding Entry No."; Integer)
        {
            Caption = 'Geocoding Entry No.';
            DataClassification = CustomerContent;
        }
    }
    keys
    {
        key(AppliesToContact; "Holding No.", "Holding Name", "Company Level") { }
    }
}
`;

// step 1: extract field(...){...} chunks that do not contain "TableRelation"
const matchedBlocks = target.match(regexp);

// step 2: extract code values
const codes = matchedBlocks.map(m => m.match(/; Code\[(\d+)\]/)[1] );
console.log(codes);
```